# What do the different coloured numbers represent

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

In battle when I inflict damage to enemies, the colour of the text is either:

- White
- Red
- Orange
- Blue

I already know when I see green I'm healing and I'm noticing Orange occurs when I inflict elemental damage which the target is weak against (ie. Light Arrows on a dark creature), But what about the other colours? They all seem to indicate damage but is there a deeper meaning to what they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue/Purple - Enemy is resistant to that damage type.

Orange/Red - Target is weak to that damage type.

White - Normal damage, no bonus.